# How to set systen UI to dark mode(not app) programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-dark-theme

I am trying to find a way to programmatically.

So far i am able to directly open the display settings menu by

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

But i can't find a way of interacting with the buttons within that preferences menu?Anything to suggest?To be more clear i am interested in setting UI dark theme programatically through an app(not the application's theme but the device's whole UI).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that is what you're looking for, but you can use the [UiModeManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager) to change the system-wide mode from you app.

Comment: I want to be able to change the ui to dark mode programmatically.not the application theme but the device's ui theme.

Comment: This does indeed affect the Ui theme of the device itself, across all apps and GUIs.

Comment: Yeah but how to use it?Can you post an example?I tried to use it and it didn't work out.Do i need special permissions in the manifest?